# java Fields not aligning right with GridBagLayout, unable to implement background image

Tags: java, image, background, alignment, gridbaglayout

So I've been working away, learning to write in java, and I'm getting close to a usable interface, but I'm having 2 problems.  When I try to implement the CloudPanel that I overrode the paint component in, it won't let me set a gridbaglayout in that panel.  To try to get everything else working while I figure out why I can't get that done, I created a new basic JPanel to fill the form with.  It's almost right, but its forcing the Price JTextField off the side of the screen or just not showing it, while the label for it is in the center of it's line instead of at the left as it should be.  Any clue what I'm doing wrong here?  ** Edit ** 2 methos of showing an image in my app are attempted to implement, but neither works. the bLogin jPanel that may be commented out for now to test the other method isn't working still, need clarification on the setPreferredSize suggestion, and when I switch the code for the imageIcon grabbagconstraints to what is showing now rather than the same as the rest of them, all jlabels and jtextfields overlap.  if I remove all lines not present in the other lGUI.add componenets then it goes back to normal except no image loading, either as a label or a background.  I've also got a bit more work to do on validation (int for ID, i'll say 6-character so I can choose my limit to modify, and double for Price, I can infer float from that I hope).  Next steps?

```
package newprovider;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.*;

/*@Michael Christopher,  author/owner */
public class NewProvider {
/** @param args the command line arguments*/

public static class CloudPanel extends JPanel {
    //paint background
    String backgroundPath="/images/CloudBack1.png";
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics cloud){
    super.paintComponent(cloud);
    Image back = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(backgroundPath)).getImage();
    cloud.drawImage(back, 0,0, this);
}
    }
public static void createGUI() {
    //build main frame
    JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();
    mainFrame.setTitle("New Provider Interface");
   // mainFrame.setOpaque(false);
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //Create the MenuBar - needs menu options
    JMenuBar maintenanceMenuBar = new JMenuBar ();
    maintenanceMenuBar.setOpaque(true);
    maintenanceMenuBar.setBackground(new Color(176,224,230));
    maintenanceMenuBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 20));
    //Create Logo
    ImageIcon LogoBox = new ImageIcon("/images/CloudBack.png");
    JLabel logoLabel = new JLabel(LogoBox);
    //create variables
    int addProviderCheck;
    String[] options = {"Yes","No"};
    String[] newExit = {"Exit", "New"};
    Dimension d = new Dimension(400, 224);

    //create labels and JTextFields
    JLabel labelID = new JLabel ("New ProviderID");
    final JTextField textID = new JTextField("providerID ", 20);
    JLabel labelName = new JLabel ("New Provider Name");
    final JTextField textName = new JTextField("Provider Name ", 20);
    JLabel labelPrice = new JLabel ("New Provider Price");
    final JTextField textPrice = new JTextField ("Price ", 20);
    //make Submit, Clear, & Exit buttons
    JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");   
    JButton clear = new JButton("Clear");
    JButton exit = new JButton("Exit");        
    //build main Panel
    CloudPanel bLogin = new CloudPanel();
    bLogin.setPreferredSize(d);
    //bLogin.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    bLogin.setOpaque(true);
    JPanel Login = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    JPanel buttonBar = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    buttonBar.setBackground(Color.red);
    buttonBar.setSize(40, 400);
    Login.setOpaque(false);
     //GridBag constraints for buttonBar and InputPane4
    GridBagConstraints bGUI = new GridBagConstraints();
    //Adding buttons to buttonBar Panel
    bGUI.insets = new Insets(5,20,5,20);
    bGUI.gridx = 0;
    bGUI.gridy = 1;
    buttonBar.add(submit,bGUI);
    bGUI.gridx = 1;
    bGUI.gridy = 1;
    buttonBar.add(clear,bGUI);
    bGUI.gridx = 2;
    bGUI.gridy = 1;
    buttonBar.add(exit,bGUI);
    //GridBag Adding Labels and Text to Login with Constraints
    GridBagConstraints lGUI = new GridBagConstraints();
    lGUI.insets = new Insets(50,15,0,0);
    lGUI.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    lGUI.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    lGUI.ipady = 100;
    lGUI.weighty = 1.0;
    lGUI.gridx = 0;
    lGUI.gridwidth = 3;
    lGUI.gridy = 0;
    Login.add(logoLabel, lGUI);
    lGUI.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    lGUI.gridx = 0;
    lGUI.gridy = 1;
    Login.add(labelID,lGUI);
    lGUI.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    lGUI.gridx = 2;
    lGUI.gridy = 1;
    Login.add(textID,lGUI);
    lGUI.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    lGUI.gridx = 0;
    lGUI.gridy = 3;
    Login.add(labelName,lGUI);
    lGUI.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    lGUI.gridx = 2;
    lGUI.gridy = 3;
    Login.add(textName,lGUI);
    lGUI.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    lGUI.gridx = 0;
    lGUI.gridy = 5;
    Login.add(labelPrice,lGUI);
    lGUI.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    lGUI.gridx = 2;
    lGUI.gridy = 5;
    Login.add(textPrice,lGUI);
    //add panels to frame
    mainFrame.add(maintenanceMenuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    //bLogin.add(Login, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    //mainFrame.add(bLogin, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    mainFrame.add(Login, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    mainFrame.add(buttonBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new FocusGrabber(clear));
    //empty fields on mouse clicks
    textID.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() { @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {textID.setText("");}
        @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
        }@Override public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
        }@Override public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
        }@Override public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
        }    }    );
    textName.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() { @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {textName.setText("");}
        @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
        }@Override public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
        }@Override public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
        }@Override public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
        }    }    );
    textPrice.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() { @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {textPrice.setText("");}
        @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
        }@Override public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
        }@Override public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
        }@Override public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
        }    }    );
    //focusListeners for Name Field
    textName.addFocusListener(new FocusListener(){ @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) { /* throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");*/ }
        @Override public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                if (!e.isTemporary()) {
                String  checkName = textName.getText();
                Boolean validName = false;
                if (checkName.isEmpty()){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainFrame, "Please enter a valid ID.");}
                else while (validName = false){try {
                        String Name = textName.getText();
                    }catch (NumberFormatException e1){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainFrame, "Please enter a valid ID.");
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new FocusGrabber(textName));
                    }finally {validName = true;}
    }    }    }    }    );
    //ActionListener for Submit button
    submit.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        String Name;
        Name = textName.getText();
        int ID = Integer.parseInt(textID.getText());
        double Price = Double.parseDouble(textPrice.getText());
        int submitPress = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                "ProviderID: " + ID + "\n" + "Provider Name: " + Name +"\n" 
                        + "Provider Price: " + Price, "Please Verify Content",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
                        null, options,options[0]);
        if (submitPress <= 0) {
            //Store Displayed data
            int providerID = ID;
            String providerName = Name;
            Double providerPrice = Price;
            System.out.println(providerID);
            System.out.println(providerName);
            System.out.println(providerPrice);//add method to store println()s to database
            //Popup Confirm dialog to reset fields or exit
            int confirmNew = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "New Provider Confirmed\n" + "Would you like to exit the module or add another provider?", "Confirmation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, null, newExit, newExit[0]);
            if (confirmNew <=0) {
                mainFrame.setVisible(false);
                mainFrame.dispose(); 
            }   else if (confirmNew > 0) {
                textID.setText("providerID");
                textName.setText("Provider Name");
                textPrice.setText("Price");
        }       }
        else if (submitPress > 0) {
            textID.setText("providerID");
            textName.setText("Provider Name");
            textPrice.setText("Price"); }
    });
    //ActionListener for clear button
    clear.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        textID.setText("providerID");
        textName.setText("Provider Name");
        textPrice.setText("Price");
    });
    //ActionListener for Exit Button
    exit.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        mainFrame.setVisible(false);
        mainFrame.dispose();
    });
//verify intent to add new provider to system before continuing
addProviderCheck = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
     "This will add a new service provider to the database.\n" 
    + "Are you sure you wish to continue?",
     "Please Verify Intent",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null, options,options[0]); 
if (addProviderCheck <= 0) {
              //Display Window
    mainFrame.pack();
    mainFrame.setSize(400, 400);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);}
else { //else close app
    mainFrame.setVisible(false);
    mainFrame.dispose();
}
  //  mainFrame.setVisible(true);
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    //draw and show the GUI
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        createGUI();
    });        
    //store new provider data
    }
}                                                                        Ive got it working (after manual resize) - well, the image as a logo is working, not the background.  I've tried defining the size different places and none of them are changing it, it starts to small and once I resize it slightly wider and nearly twice as tall it then snaps to proper alignment.  Here's the pieces I added:   
    mainFrame.setSize(new Dimension(800,425));
    ImageIcon LogoBox = new ImageIcon("images/CloudBack.png");
    JLabel logoLabel = new JLabel(LogoBox);                                                                                                                        
    //create panel to stack logo and login
    JPanel logFrame = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    logFrame.setOpaque(false);                                                              [....Unchanged code...]
    JPanel Login = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    Login.setSize(800, 425);
    JPanel buttonBar = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    buttonBar.setBackground(Color.red);
    buttonBar.setSize(40, 400);
    Login.setOpaque(false);                                               [....Unchanged code....]                         
    Login.add(textPrice,lGUI);
    //GridBag Adding login and logo to panel
    GridBagConstraints pGUI = new GridBagConstraints();
    pGUI.insets = new Insets(5,10,15,20);
    pGUI.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    pGUI.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    pGUI.ipady = 400;
    pGUI.weighty = 1.0;
    pGUI.gridx = 0;
    pGUI.gridy = 0;
    logFrame.add(logoLabel, pGUI);
    pGUI.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
    pGUI.gridx = 0;
    pGUI.gridy = 1;
    logFrame.add(Login, pGUI);                                        [....Unchanged Code....]
    mainFrame.add(logFrame, BorderLayout.CENTER);                        [....Unchanged Code....]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> . When I try to implement the CloudPanel that I overrode the paint component in, it won't let me set a gridbaglayout in that panel.

Not sure exactly what you are asking but I notice two problems.

1. You create a CloudPanel instance but then you never do anything with that instance. That is you don't add the panel to another panel or add any components to the panel.
2. You don't override the `getPreferredSize()` method of the CloudPanel class to be the size of the image. Therefore the size will be (0, 0) so you can't add it to another panel.

Also, you should never to I/O in a painting method. The painting method will be called whenever Swing determines the component needs to be repainted and you don't want to keep reading the image.

Comment: JPanel Login was being called as CloudPanel Login = new CloudPanel(new GridBagLayout());    but it was giving me an illegal arguments error (arguments required none, arguments found gridbaglayout) so I changed it to a JPanel till I could figure out the problem so I could get the rest of it aligned and working.   I'll look at getPreferredSize(), but if I'm using a horribly inefficient way of using a main background image, what would be a better way to do it?

Comment: Using a panel to paint a background image is fine. The reason you can't create the CloudPanel with a LayoutManager is because you didn't define a constructor that accepts a LayoutManager as a parameter. You can either create a constructor for the LayoutManager or set the layout after you create the panel by using: `fieldBox.setLayout(....)`.

Comment: switched to GridBagConstraints and anchors and fixed that, now just the background image problem remains

Comment: What image problem? Are you read the image properly? Does the image have a size? If not the only thing I can suggest is to get rid of the leading "/" in the filename. You don't want to look at the root of your drive. Better yet read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) for a better way to read the images.

Comment: I'm trying to use the image as a background image, overlaying the Login panel and buttonBar panel on top of it., and the size is 400x224 pixels.  I did look over that tutorial, but none of it covers using image as a background, with labels and jtextfields on top of it.

Comment: If you are labels or text fields to the CloudPanel then it is just like another other panel, you set the layout and add the components. If you add a panel to the CloudPanel, then by default the panel is opaque and will just paint over top of the CloudPanel so you won't see the image. You need to make your "login panel" non-opaque by using the `setOpaque(false)` method.

Comment: its loading now, though I have to resize the window to be taller to make all the labels and textfields show up.  I can't get it to open the right size.

Comment: Don't use setSize(). use pack().

Comment: that moved it forwards, but its got an empty space slightly larger than the .png between the image and the rest of the JLabels and JTextfields.  I can only see it all now if I maximize the frame after running.

Comment: I'm not going to debug the entire code for you. Start with something simple. One or two components and get it working the way you want. Then if it doesn't work you have a simple [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to post. Then once that works you add a few more components. The point of the answers you received here is to understand the basic concept. So simplify the problem until you understand the concept. Don't write the whole application before you start debugging.

Comment: Thanks camickr.  The only and entire purpose of this app is for me to learn how to make the pieces and make them work together. I  kept adding as I solved each smaller piece, expecting to start over when done with everything in the right relative place.  Then I forget to trim back the solved pieces to leave just the problem.  PLEASE correct me if i'm wrong, but I think what I need to do now is start building classes and methods as separate .java files that I can call and use to build the GUI, or any similar GUI, instead of trying to pack all the code into one java file.  Any guides for that?

Comment: Yes, you always try to create reusable code. I don't have any guidelines on how to do this. Just experience.

Comment: sorry let me re-phrase.  I have started ones that "implements" or "extends" but I have no clue how to structure one that is simply a set of methods that are reusable that do not extend or implement anything other than if/else/do/while/get/set, and have no main.  That's what I was looking for guides for, and probably am not finding because my phrasing is terrible.

Comment: Well typically reusable code does extend or implement something because you are creating reusable small chunks of generic code to plug into the existing Java API. For example your code could use the `ExitAction` found in [Closing an Application](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/). Instead of creating a CloudPanel you create a more general purpose panel. See [Background Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/).

Comment: Other times you might have a set of helper methods that perform common functionality. These methods tend to be static. Check out the `SwingUtilities` class in the API for an example. Check out the [Text Utiltities](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/26/text-utilities/) as another example. These are some common functions you might want to use on text components. Or, maybe you have a group of methods the manipulate an Image so you create "ImageUtilities".

Comment: thanks, those helped a lot.  restarting at the right level (I hope)  I have a <20 line class that is the root of a lot of problems in the bigger code.  it "seems" fine, but is not doing the only thing it's supposed to do.  Should I post that as a new thread, better tagged, so I can use that base to build all the other methods and classes i'll need, or should I do it here?

Comment: This thread is finished. Remember when you ask a question when code is causing a problem you should post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). This is the minimal executable code (including the main() method) that will replicate the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your textPrice field does not show up because you are not adding it to the panel, do just a minor change to one line of code,

```
lGUI.gridx = 0;
lGUI.gridy = 3;
Login.add(labelPrice,lGUI);
lGUI.gridx = 1;
lGUI.gridy = 3;
Login.add(textPrice,lGUI);  <===== this one, you are adding labelPrice again
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm not sure how I missed that.